# Separate a column in two using just R base functions

Tags: r

i got this df:

```
df = data.frame(
                date = c(01/01/2020, 01/02/2020, 01/03/2020), 
                day = c("Rain31", "Rain12", "Rain04")
)

        date    day 
1 01/01/2020 Rain31 
2 01/02/2020 Rain12 
3 01/03/2020 Rain04
```

and i want to reach this:

```
        date    day   true.day
1 01/01/2020 Rain31 31/01/2020
2 01/02/2020 Rain12 12/02/2020
3 01/03/2020 Rain04 01/03/2020
```

i can do this with separate() and unite()

but now, i can use just base functions :(

what i have done: (not important for the resolution)

```
  df %>%
    separate(day,  into = c("rain", "nday"), sep = 4  ) %>%
    separate(date, into = c("day", "month_year"), sep = 3) %>%
    unite(DataPrecMax, nday, month_year, sep = "")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove non-digits from `day` column and replace first 2 characters of `date`.

```
df$true.date <- df$date
substring(df$true.date, 1, 2) <- sub('\\D+', '', df$day)
df
#        date    day  true.date
#1 01/01/2020 Rain31 31/01/2020
#2 01/02/2020 Rain12 12/02/2020
#3 01/03/2020 Rain04 04/03/2020
```

**data**

```
df = data.frame(
  date = c("01/01/2020", "01/02/2020", "01/03/2020"), 
  day = c("Rain31", "Rain12", "Rain04"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: perfect. can u explain to me what sub() is doing? '\\D+' is an strange argument

Comment: It removes all characters from `day` column which are not numbers. So for example from first value it removes "Rain" and keeps only "31" similarly, for all other values as well. If in `day` column the value is always "Rain" + number, you can also use `sub('Rain', '', df$day)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_replace`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(true.day = str_replace(date, '..', str_remove(day, 'Rain')))
#.       date    day   true.day
#1 01/01/2020 Rain31 31/01/2020
#2 01/02/2020 Rain12 12/02/2020
#3 01/03/2020 Rain04 04/03/2020
```

---

If we need only `base R` functions

```
df$true.day <- with(df, sub("^..(\\S+)\\s+\\D+(\\d+)", "\\2\\1", paste(date, day)))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(
  date = c("01/01/2020", "01/02/2020", "01/03/2020"), 
  day = c("Rain31", "Rain12", "Rain04"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: i just can use the base functions :/

Comment: @BryanSouza thanks, updated with `base R` only functions

Comment: thanks a lot! but where can i read about this: "^..(\\S+)\\s+\\D+(\\d+)" ? it seems to be complex

Comment: @BryanSouza I would say if you understand couple of things i.e `\\S`=> non white space, `\\s`=> white space, `\\D`=> non-digit, `\\d` - digit. and `+` => one or more of the characters (i.e. either non white space, white space) etc. along with `()` => capture group, `^` => start of string, `.`=> any character.  it becomes easier. Here, the pattern is to search after two characters `..` from the start (`^)`, capture all non white space (`(\\S+`)) followed by one or more white space (`\\s+`), non-digits \\D+, and the secon capture (`\\d+`).  In replacement, use the backreference of capture grp